# MySQL database - Error: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'barginadmin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: sql, azure-mysql-database

Note: i tried every single stackoverflow suggestion at the bottom before I posted.. I also tried creating the user in the database on the mySQL command line then granting all permissions, still no luck.

I have a MySQL database through Azure. I have everything set up with SQL WorkBench and Azure Data Studio. I can do basic commands on the server like SHOW, SELECT, USE, CREATE. However, I do not have access to LOAD DATA INFILE. The error I receive is the following: `Error: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'barginadmin'@'%' (using password: YES)`.

I need the LOAD DATA INFILE command so I can load large csv files into the database.

[image]

I am the only user on this database as I created it on Azure Portal this morning. I would ASSUME I would have admin rights. I have already tried a heap of things such us granting all the permissions to admin on the server, I have tried flushing the permissions.

Please, knowledgeable people of stackoverflow - help!

Tried to use LOAD DATA INFILE, as well as LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, neither I have permission for despite being logged into the server and the only user..

Comment: apologies, i updated the correct name... also - attached an image of the mysql command I am trying to run. I need to grant myself FILE but cant do to the error.

Comment: @Phil when I check the users on my database, I dont even have a root user. Will this matter? When I attempt to sign in with mysql -u root -p and enter my password, I am able to get in but its not even a user on the mysql.user list

Comment: If you can connect using root, try granting your `barginadmin` user the `FILE` permission. Then reconnect using `barginadmin` and try your `LOAD DATA` command again

Comment: `FILE` privilige in Azure MySQL is not supported. `LOAD DATA INFILE` is supported with limitations. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-limitations

Comment: I ran the following: 'grant all privileges on barginsense.* to 'barginadmin'@'%' with grant option;' then for good measure I also granted FILE like `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'barginadmin'@'%';` . I then did 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'. I exited, and logged back in as barginadmin. I did `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'barginadmin'@'%';` and I see file in there now. Problem is - when I loginto barginadmin and i check the list of databases i dont see the one from Azure. I just see the 4 generic ones. I don't know why they aren't connected